# Wire ends avoiding each other when trying to connect as well as going around pads instead of connecting to them

Tags: pcb, altium

[image]I am working on altium designer v20.0.13 and for some reason when I am trying to connect the components with routes the routes are avoiding each other when I am trying to connect them together as well as going around pads instead of connecting to them.

Comment: Are they connected in the schematic?  I would expect that's how a smart router would behave if the pads aren't called out as being connected in the netlist, and the netlist is generated by the schematic.

Comment: seems so , I just rechecked and it does show the connection as a 'wire' and the net name

Comment: When you turn on the ratsnest view, do the connections show properly?

Comment: no it doesn't but i thought it was just some view settings I had not turned on

Comment: Just for grins, remove the connection from the schematic then add it back and regenerate the rats nest  from the new net list, and see if that solves it. I have had similar things happen in another CAD program and learned to fix it that way. I did not have to change the layout. After that the rats nets showed the connection and the trace connected properly.